# How to delete an record from Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I have an Django model as follows:

```
class Calculations(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(to=Customer, null=True, blank=True)
    data = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and customer model as follows:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

I want to delete one record from the customer. I do it as follows:

```
Customer.objects.filter(id=some_id).delete()
```

But that deletes `customer` and also `calculation`.

I should probably use `on_delete`, thus something like:

```
customer = models.ForeignKey(to=Customer, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models....)
```

But, what I want is:

- if I delete `calculation` then I want to delete also the customer,
- but if I delete an record from `customer` I want only that the customer is deleted and that the `customer_id` from calculations is deleted, thus not the whole calculation record.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the `customer` when you delete a `calculation`:

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.customer.delete()
    super(Calculations, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

To avoid deleting the `calculation` when you delete a `customer`:

```
customer = models.ForeignKey(to=Customer, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```